# XSLT: Xpath query with expanded value returns "node exists" when no such node is present

Tags: xml, xslt

Please consider following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:template name="getServiceDef">
        <services>
            <service>
                <serviceName>service</serviceName>
                <parameters>
                    <param1/>
                    <param2/>
                    <param3/>
                </parameters>
            </service>
        </services>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="getInput">
        <parameters>
            <param1>10</param1>
            <param2>single</param2>
            <param3>2</param3>
            <param4>650</param4>
            <param5>750</param5>
        </parameters>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="serviceDef">
            <xsl:call-template name="getServiceDef"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="inputParameters">
            <xsl:call-template name="getInput"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:for-each select="$inputParameters/parameters/param4">
            <xsl:variable name="currentParameterName" select="./local-name()"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$serviceDef/services/service/parameters/$currentParameterName">
                    <xsl:message>
                        $currentParameterName '<xsl:value-of select="$currentParameterName"/>'exists.
                        $serviceDef/services/service/parameters/param4 '<xsl:value-of select="$serviceDef/services/service/parameters/param4"/>'
                        $serviceDef/services/service/parameters/$currentParameterName '<xsl:value-of select="$serviceDef/services/service/parameters/$currentParameterName"/>' 
                    </xsl:message>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:message>param '<xsl:value-of select="$currentParameterName"/>' does NOT exist</xsl:message>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In block of code starting with line

```
<xsl:for-each select="$inputParameters/parameters/param4">
```

I am trying to decide, whether node  exists also in $serviceDef. It does not. However if the XPATH query is executed with expanded variable, query is evaluated as "node exists" (console output below).

**Question:
Why query 
$serviceDef/services/service/parameters/param4 returns "False" and
$serviceDef/services/service/parameters/$currentParameterName returns "True" ? 
I would expect that queries are identical.**

To replicate:

1. Copy code above to file stackOverFlowReplication.xsl
2. laptop:~$ echo "<notneeded/>" > sample.xml
3. laptop:~$ java -jar saxon9pe.jar -s:sample.xml -xsl:stackOverFlowReplication.xsl

Console output:

```
No license file found - running with licensable features disabled
Warning at xsl:stylesheet on line 2 column 125 of stackOverFlowReplication.xsl:
  Running an XSLT 10 stylesheet with an XSLT 20 processor

        $currentParameterName 'param4'exists.
        $serviceDef/services/service/parameters/param4 ''
        $serviceDef/services/service/parameters/$currentParameterName 'param4'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to expect that `test="$serviceDef/services/service/parameters/$currentParameterName"` constructs an XPath expression at run-time, based on your variable inserted in that last step. That does not happen, you simply evaluate the variable reference `$currentParameterName` in the last step and it evaluates to the string `param4` and any non-empty string in the a boolean context like the `xsl:when/xsl:if test` evaluates to true.

You either need to use `xsl:evaluate` provided in XSLT 3.0 for dynamic XPath evaluation or for your simple case you can use e.g. `test="$serviceDef/services/service/parameters/*[local-name() = $currentParameterName]"`.

To give you an idea of what your expression evaluates to, see http://xsltransform.net/naZXpX1 which does

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs fo">
    <xsl:template name="getServiceDef">
        <services>
            <service>
                <serviceName>service</serviceName>
                <parameters>
                    <param1/>
                    <param2/>
                    <param3/>
                </parameters>
            </service>
        </services>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="getInput">
        <parameters>
            <param1>10</param1>
            <param2>single</param2>
            <param3>2</param3>
            <param4>650</param4>
            <param5>750</param5>
        </parameters>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="serviceDef">
            <xsl:call-template name="getServiceDef"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="inputParameters">
            <xsl:call-template name="getInput"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:for-each select="$inputParameters/parameters/param4">
            <xsl:variable name="currentParameterName" select="./local-name()"/>
            <xsl:variable name="exp1" select="$serviceDef/services/service/parameters/$currentParameterName"/>
            <debug-help string-sequence-test="{$exp1 instance of xs:string*}" node-sequence-test="{$exp1 instance of node()*}" value="{$exp1}"/>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which outputs `<debug-help string-sequence-test="true" node-sequence-test="false" value="param4"/>` so it shows you never have a node sequence, but simply a sequence of a single string with your variable value.

Comment: You are right, I expected precisely behavior you described. It didn't occur to me that I am in fact evaluating variable reference. Thanks a lot for explanation, it makes sense. As I am forced to use XSLT 1.0, I'll use example you provided. Thanks again for prompt and correct response.

Comment: If you are using XSLT 1.0 then consider to use an XSLT 1.0 processor to test your code as there `$serviceDef/services/service/parameters/$currentParameterName` would not even work syntactically but rather give you a syntax error.